# Las funciones escritas dentro de una clase son llamadas métodos ¿Cómo se llaman las variables escritas dentro de una clase?

Tags: python

```
 class Pregunta(object):
        # método
        def foo(self): 
            pass
        # ¿Esto es una variable o tiene algun otro nombre?
        bar = 'tijuana'
```

¿Las variables dentro de una clase reciben otro nombre al igual que las funciones son llamadas metodos ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se llaman atributos si se declaran y se les asigna valor en la misma clase.

No se debe confundir con propiedades, que son un tipo de atributo, que solamente se declara en la clase, pero no se les asigna valor en la misma declaración (o se les asigna valor None), sino que se les asigna valor en una instancia de esa clase.

Con los métodos **__get__**, **__set__**, y **__delete__** puedes regular el comportamiento de las propiedades, y el acceso a ellas desde otras clases.

En este [artículo](http://codehero.co/python-desde-cero-clases-atributos-y-metodos/) puedes hacerte una idea general de cómo usar los atributos y clases en python.

En este [otro](http://stackabuse.com/python-properties/) puedes encontrar más información acerca del manejo de propiedades.

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Andrés

Si no me equivoco son llamadas atributos, en el caso que planteas, el atributo bar del objeto Pregunta y se podría hacer referencia a él de la siguiente forma:

```
Pregunta.bar
```

En la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) viene mas ampliamente explicado

Espero que te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 1):

La *nomeclatura* está bien usarla para hacernos entender, pero si fuéramos estrictors no habría forma de aclarse.

Todo objeto en python tiene un *"diccionario"* asociado que se puede ver mediante la función `vars`. Las clases, como objetos que son, también tiene su diccionario y se formaría con ese "espacio de nombres" que se crea cuando defines la clase.

Los items del diccionario de un objetos son los *"atributos"*, y los de una clase se conocen por **"atributo de clase"** (<< *ésta sería la respuesta corta a tu pregunta*).

Por **función** se entiende un fragmento de código que toma valores como entrada y devuelve un resultado como salida. En python no existen las *"funciones puras"*. Siempre que definimos una *función* lo que en realidad creamos es un objeto *"descriptor"*. Con los descriptores se implementan los *"métodos"* y *"propiedades"*, y son los responsables de que funcione la *"herencia"*.

Un **método** se define como un fragmento de código cuya instanciación crea **clausuras** que dan un contexto de ejecución. Visto de otro modo, los métodos son clases cuyas instancias son las clausuras. Para crear métodos, se asignan descriptores como atributos de clase.

...y creo que me voy a parar aquí.

Answer (score 0):

Son *variables globales.*

Pueden ser usadas dentro de cualquier método de la clase donde es declarada.
Si es privada, solo puede ser usada por la clase que la declara.

Ejemplo:

```
namespace {

    private int valor;

    public class Saludos {

        public void metodo1() {
            valor = 1;
        }
    }
}
```